# How to make a meshgrid with holes in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-3.6

I understand how to make a simple meshgrid like this one:

```
low1 = -1; high1 = 1;
n_p = 20
range1 = np.linspace(low1, high1,n_p/2, endpoint=False)
X = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(range1, range1)).reshape(-1, 2)
```

[image]

But what is the best way to make a meshgrid like on the picture below?

[image]

Right now I am just building 8 rectangles and stack them. What is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Better in what respect? If your solution works then I think it's best because it doesn't need any more work...

Comment: @Julien It is too many lines of code for a seemingly simple task: three more ranges, eight more square grids, and one line stacking of them. Can it be done with some vector operation?

Comment: I don't think `meshgrid` is the right word once you do the `reshape` above - to me, a meshgrid is a multi-dimensional array of coordinates, not just a 1D array of coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the outer rectangle first, then take out the inner rectangle with a filter:

```
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20, endpoint=False)
X = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(x, x)).reshape(-1, 2)       # outer rectangle

X[(np.abs(X + 0.1) > 1).any(1)].shape                 # take out the inner rectangle
# (300, 2)   300 = 20 * 20 (outer) - 10 * 10 (inner)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bool mask:

```
low1 = -1; high1 = 1;
n_p = 20
range1 = np.linspace(low1, high1,n_p//2, endpoint=False)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(range1, range1)
mask = ~((X < 0.4) & (X > -0.4) & (Y < 0.4) & (Y > -0.4))
np.c_[X[mask], Y[mask]]
```